# Snowflake DROP TABLE table_name(...)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why the below syntax does not error out:

```
CREATE TABLE a1 AS SELECT 1 a;

TRUNCATE TABLE a1(sth);
-- SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 17 unexpected '('.

DROP TABLE a1(sth);
-- A1 successfully dropped.
-- here I would expect an error
```

Both [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/truncate-table.html) and [DROP TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/drop-table.html) take parameter `<name>`

> Specifies the identifier for the table to drop. If the identifier contains spaces, special characters, or mixed-case characters, the entire string must be enclosed in double quotes. Identifiers enclosed in double quotes are also case-sensitive (e.g. "My Object").

Is there a special behaviour for `table_name(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "drop table", the table name does not accept any parameters so it should not accept any parentheses. Please open a ticket and report this bug to Snowflake.